# Facing error while using image_picker in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, androidx

Hy, I am new to flutter and while working with an app that uses image_picker to get images from the gallery I was facing this error.

```
C:\Users\Hrishabh Mishra\Desktop\FDR\Flutter\course\08\mycameraapp>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 5 Pro in debug mode...
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:15: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
                             ^
  symbol:   class ActivityCompat
  location: package android.support.v4.app
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:17: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:3: error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
                                 ^
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerFileProvider.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
public class ImagePickerFileProvider extends FileProvider {}
                                             ^
  symbol: class FileProvider
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:8: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
                                 ^
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY = 2342;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_IMAGE_WITH_CAMERA = 2343;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_IMAGE_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2344;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_IMAGE_PERMISSION = 2345;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_VIDEO_FROM_GALLERY = 2352;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_VIDEO_WITH_CAMERA = 2353;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_VIDEO_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 2354;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_VIDEO_PERMISSION = 2355;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting final String fileProviderName;
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:164: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerDelegate
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerPlugin.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
  @VisibleForTesting
   ^
  symbol:   class VisibleForTesting
  location: class ImagePickerPlugin
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
            return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permissionName)
                   ^
  symbol: variable ActivityCompat
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] {permissionName}, requestCode);
            ^
  symbol: variable ActivityCompat
H:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker-0.4.12+1\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepicker\ImagePickerDelegate.java:140: error: cannot find symbol
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, fileProviderName, file);
                   ^
  symbol: variable FileProvider
20 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':image_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.  
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

```
BUILD FAILED in 28s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        32.5s
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin image_picker...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   22.3s
WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'false'
Consider disabling R8 by removing 'android.enableR8=true' from your gradle.properties before publishing your app.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'imagepicker'.   
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

- Try:
  Run with `--stacktrace` option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

The plugin image_picker could not be built due to the issue above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or 
with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

Configure the Android SDK first.

Method 1:

1. Go to Settings
2. Expand Language & Frameworks
3. Select Flutter
4. Enter the flutter sdk path in *Flutter SDK Path* textbox
5. Click Ok

Method 2:

Flutter provides a command to update the Android SDK path:

```
Use flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```